# HTTP Server & CGI Processing

Tags: c, http, cgi

I have a homework assignment that I am supposed to write a http server that is supposed to process an input given in a form on my index.html page. To do this I have a form that uses the POST action and links to a cgi file. The problem that I am having is linking to my cgi file. My index file and the cgi file are in the same folder so my form looks something like this:

```
    <form action="test.cgi" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

When I connect to my server I connect to: localhost:PORT which gives me the index file and when I hit the submit button I get linked to localhost:PORT/test.cgi

In my mind this should directly link me to my cgi file and everything should work. I know that this must be because I do not understand how the server organizes the files on my computer. Could someone explain to me how this works?

If I didn't post some vital information just let me know and I will edit the post as soon as possible.

Comment: I suspect you're not writing a "http server" but rather just a cgi script, yes?

Comment: Well if you wrote the server it's your job to debug it as much as you can and tell us what code is not behaving as expected.  If you didn't write it, then you ha e left lots of important info out of your post.

Comment: @BrianRoach I actually am writing a http server as well as a cgi script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing the HTTP server, you can define the 'rules' of CGI processing :-)

Apache, for example, by default requires one to place CGI scripts in cgi-bin directory to enable their execution. This is all configurable via httpd.conf - so user can disable CGI or specify another directory for CGI scripts via the configuration file - you may choose to do something similar.

Also note that the file extensions for CGI files are typically test.pl (for perl scripts) and the server usually does a fork/exec of the specified script file

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html is a good reference

Comment: Alright so it sounds like I have to define all the 'rules' for CGI processing on my server. Also I understand that perl or python scripts would be easier for the CGI files but the assignment specifically wants everything to be done in c, which makes everything a bit more complicated

Comment: your web server will be in C, but it typically will exec a perl process or some other process that can understand the script language in which your server expects users to write CGI scripts in - as a web server, your C code is only responsible for exec-ing the cgi script and managing its output, lifecycle - the script itself is a black box to the web server